# Distinguish HTTP from HTTPS in Force.com Sites

Tags: apex, force.com-sites

I'm developing on Force.com Sites, and having trouble distinguishing whether the current request is coming in on HTTP or HTTPS.  Do you have any tips?

```
ApexPages.CurrentPage().getUrl();
// ==> relative url without the domain or protocol

ApexPages.CurrentPage().getHeaders() 
// doesn't dependably include any url information
```

Comment: Once you know whether it is HTTP or HTTPS, what do you plan to do? ;-)

Comment: Use a `<page action={!actionFunction}` to force the HTTP request to reload in HTTPS for a few particularly sensitive pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [URL](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_url.htm) class:

```
System.debug('URL Protocol: ' + URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getProtocol());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Site.getCurrentSiteUrl()
// Returns: https://sites-labs-demo-developer-edition.na9.force.com/test
```

Comment: This would totally work, but I ended up going with Daniel's approach and its handy `getProtocol` shortcut